# How do call a function when component is focussed or on screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know in React native it's possible to use this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/

but is it possible to say do a similar thing when a user scrolls to a particular component or when that component is visible on the screen?

(obviously mount / useEffect is different as the component could mount but not be visible on the screen at that point)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [Intersection Observer Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

and see if there's a popular React component around it or create one yourself.